# Adding a Managed Package to home page in Salesforce Mobile

Tags: page-layout, mobile, package, home-page-component

When I add an installed package to account page and activate it, it asks me whether it should be applied to both desktop and mobile:

[image]

But when I do the same in home page, it doesn't ask.
Is there a way to enable an installed package in home page of Salesforce Mobile?

Answer (score 1):

There are three types of pages in the Lightning App builder:

- App Page
- Home Page
- Record Page

The Home Page is configurable only for desktop, because Mobile App always runs under a specific Salesforce application. You can configure your App Page for Salesforce Mobile so that it's the first page your user will be navigated to, and hence it becomes your home page:

1. Create a new App Page, give it a name and place your components on the canvas
2. Click on Activate -> Lightning Experience tab and choose the app you want to add the App Page to (this should be the app your users are using in Salesforce Mobile, in my example it is the LightningSales app). The App Page you're adding to the app has to be on the first place so that it's the first page they go to. Also see the following part of [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.lightning_page_getting_into_salesforce1.htm&type=5):

> The first item that you put in the mobile navigation list becomes your users’ landing page.
> [image]

3. Go to Setup -> App Manager -> Find your app and click the chevron and Edit -> App Options -> Disable end user personalization of nav items in this app (otherwise your page will appear at the end of the list and will not become the landing page)
   [image]

[See this](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.lightning_app_builder_create_app_page.htm&type=5) for more details.

Your Salesforce Mobile user will see the following (perhaps with a different language configured, mine is Czech):

[image]

Whether the components from the package you installed will render or not depends on whether they have been implemented for the mobile form factor.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

For Salesforce Mobile application there is nothing like Home page, U can create an App page and use it as first page in application.

Comment: Sorry, but how is this any better / different from the (more detailed) existing answer?!